# How to pass information back with view controllers

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiviewcontroller, uistoryboard

I have a view controller and one table View Controller. I go from VC One to VCTable. On VCTable, I select a(cell) data from type string that I store in value. When I press a cell, I would like to send that data back to VC One.
and show in button or label.

How to do this using Storyboards?

Comment: How do you show VC Two? From VC One? Does VC Two mean VCTable?

Comment: sorry ,yeah .From VC One

Comment: Ok, I will show you some simple way :)

Comment: yes. VCtable is json API that I select one city and show in VC one :D

Comment: Please check my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you should take a look at **protocols** / **delegation**:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Protocols.html

Answer (score 0):

**First Solution: Using CallBack**

In your VCOne:

```
@IBAction func goToViewController2(sender: AnyObject) {
        let vc2 = storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("ViewController2") as! ViewController2
        vc2.callback = ({ string in
            self.myString = string
        })
        presentViewController(vc2, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
```

in your VCTable:

create a callback variable:

```
var callback: ((String) -> Void)?
```

in your `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` method, send it to VCOne by:

```
callback?(textField.text!)
```

**Second Solution: Using Reference**

```
@IBAction func goToViewController2(sender: AnyObject) {
        let vc2 = storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("ViewController2") as! ViewController2
        vc2.vc1 = self
        presentViewController(vc2, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
```

in your VCTable:

create this variable:

```
var vc1: ViewController?
```

in your `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` method, send it to VCOne by:

```
vc1?.myString = textField.text!
```

**Third Solution: Using Delegate** see the link as @Andre Slotta said.

**FourthSolution: Using CenterNotification** Googling for this :).

Hope this help :)

Comment: What do you think that is a better way ?

Comment: There is no better way here, you can choose one if you feel it easy for you.